# I am trying to get Postman connected with SAP HANA ADVANCE API via oauth 2.0?

Tags: postman, hana, xsodata

I have been shared with Username and Password of SAP HANA X ADVANCE. I can successfully login from a web browser and see the list of web services.

I want to connect my API Client (Postman) with SAP API can you help me from where I can get the values of following fields?

[image]